# Seit wann ist ein "Wurm" nur noch ein Wurm und kein anderes Insekt?

Tags: history, meaning

Heutzutage versteht man unter einem Wurm ein bein- und wirbelloses Kriechtier wie auf folgendem Bild:

[Bild eines Regenwurms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/520Y0.jpg)
<sup>Wikimedia</sup>

Das war aber möglicherweise nicht immer so. So nennt man im übertragenen Sinn auch ein hilfsbedürftiges Kind *"[Wurm](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wurm_Kind_Wesen)"*, was ja noch mit der heutigen Bedeutung von *"Wurm"* erklärt werdn kann. Aber auch Insekten und Käfer werden manchmal noch im zusammengesetzten Namen als *"Würmchen"* bezeichnet:

> - **Marienkäfer**:  Marienwürmchen
> - **Leuchtkäfer**:  Glühwürmchen

Und dann gibt es ja auch noch den ***["Lindwurm"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindwurm)***, ein drachenartiges Fabeltier, das nicht einmal ein Insekt ist.

Noch im 19. Jahrhundert findet man ähnliche Aussagen wie diese:

> *Die Würmchen summen lustig durch die Blätter,
>
>   die Blümchen schließen ihre Augen auf.* <sup>[Grillparzer](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW29054)</sup>

Gab es also in der Neuzeit einen Bedeutungswandel des Wortes *Wurm* oder *Würmchen*? Und - falls ja - ist etwas bekannt darüber warum und seit wann das so ist?

Comment: Was für Drogen nimmst du eigentlich, wenn du solche Fragen stellst :D Naja, das mit dem Kind würde ich wiefolgt verstehen: Soweit ich weiß, bezieht sich das auf Kleinstkinder/Babies. Diese sind noch nicht in der Lage zu laufen/gehen, können teilweise ja nicht mal krabbeln oder robben. Wurm kommt vom mittelhochdeutschen wurm (wer hätte es gedacht?), und bedeutet soviel wie Kriechtier, Schlange und auch Insekt, und laut Duden genaugenommen Sichwindende. In jedem Fall etwas, was seine Beine, Füße entw. nicht hat, bzw. (bezogen auf das Kind) nicht benutzen kann. Klingt das schlüssig?

Comment: @Em1: so oganz schlüssig will mir das nicht sein. Sowohl ein *Marienwürmchen* als auch ein *Glühwürmchen* können nicht nur krabbeln sondern sogar fliegen - von Kriechen, Schlängeln etc. keine Spur.

Comment: Wenn Du's _wirklich_ wissen willst, [im Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW29054) steht unendlich viel dazu. (Und vergiss nicht, dass "Wurm" auch verächtlich als Schimpfwort gebraucht werden kann.)

Comment: @Takkat Habe mich ja auch nur auf die Kinder bezogen. Ach, und um das ganze noch etwas komplexer zu machen: Es gibt imho auch Tiere mit *Wurm* im Namen, die auch aussehen wie ein Wurm (also keine Füßchen haben), jedoch zur Gattung der *Gliederfüßer (Arthropoda)* gehört. Diese Gattung hat widerum Füße oder zumindest evolutionsbedingte Überreste von Füßen (also im Falle dieser Würmer)

Comment: Zu dem Lindwurm nur kurz: althochdeutsch lint: Schlange. Der Lindwurm kennzeichnet sich weniger dadurch dass er/es ein drachenartiges Fabeltier ist, sondern ein schlangenartiges Fabelwesen, mit der äußeren Erscheinung dessen, was wir als Drachen kennen.

Comment: Die Frage wurmt Dich, @Takkat :)

Comment: Bedeutungsverlust? Da muss der Wurm drin sein!

Comment: "Arthropoda" (Gliederfüßer) sind ein "Stamm". darunter gibt es dann u.a. Ordnungen (Spinnentiere, Krebstiere, Insekten), Familien (Kurzflügelkäfer, Laufkäfer, Springspinnen, Trichterspinnen), **Gattungen** (Grabkäfer), Arten (Siebenpunktmarienkäfer, kupferfarbener Laufkäfer) etc. Wenn schon sprachliche Korrektheit, dann auch fachliche ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%BCrmer) wurden "im Mittelalter oft noch vielerlei andere „kriechende Tiere“ als Würmer bezeichnet".

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wurm_Kriechtier_Schlange) belehrt uns, dass "Wurm" "der Sichwindende" bedeutet (Althochdeutsch).

Wir können also davon ausgehen, dass der Begriff schon länger existiert. Ebenso können wir davon ausgehen, dass im Mittelalter nicht die gleichen Begriffsunterscheidungen in der Biologie vorgenommen wurden, wie es heute der Fall ist. Schon gar nicht von der breiten Masse.

Wenn sich also etwas wie ein Wurm wand, war es schnell ein Wurm, selbst wenn bei genauerer Betrachtung Beinchen zu sehen waren. Selbst wenn es sich nicht wand, sondern nur wie ein Wurm aussah, ist davon auszugehen, dass viele es als Wurm bezeichneten. Wie zum Beispiel Larven von Insekten oder flügellose Insekten wie das weibliche [Glühwürmchen](http://www.laternentanz.eu/Content/Informations/Living.aspx#Name):

[image: Glühwürmchenweibchen (herrlicher Begriff :)]

> Die volkstümliche Bezeichnung Glühwürmchen leitet sich wohl von den Larven oder den flügellosen Weibchen ab, die aufgrund einer sehr flüchtigen Betrachtung einige unserer Vorfahren an einen Wurm erinnerten.

Der Wurm war vermutlich noch nie ein Insekt. Da Menschen aber Fehler machen (und über die Jahrhunderte hunderte Menschen hunderte Fehler) gab und gibt es falsche Bezeichnungen, die sich hartnäckig halten, auch wenn mittlerweile angepasste Alternativen wie "[Leuchtkäfer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leuchtk%C3%A4fer)" existieren.

Comment: Mein Begriff des Tages: Glühwürmchenweibchen

Comment: Den Begriff "falsche Bezeichnung" möchte ich hier entschieden zurückweisen. Wenn die Bezeichnung von der Mehrheit aller Menschen (nämlich all jenen, die ihn nicht aus einem Biologiebuch haben) verwendet wird, dann ist der Begriff nicht falsch, sondern allenfalls irreführend. Demnächst erklärt noch jemand den Begriff "Erdbeere" für falsch, weil die Erdbeere ja keine Beere, sondern eine Nuss ist und deshalb korrekter Erdnuss genannt werden müsste (dass es "Erdnuss" bereits gibt, macht nichts, denn im Gegensatz zur Erdbeere ist die Erdnuss *keine* Nuss, und muss somit auch umbenannt werden).

Comment: Der Begriff "Insekt" und die Unterscheidung nach solchen Merkmalen wie Anzahl der Beine, Untergliederung des Körpers etc. ist ja eher eine neue Erfindung. Intuitiver ist es vielleicht erstmal, nach Aussehen, Verhalten (Isst es meinen Kohl oder nicht? Kann es fliegen?) etc. zu unterscheiden. Die Unterscheidung Wurm-Insekt gab es ja bis vor kurzem nicht, sondern mehr Wurm-Käfer-Spinne-Fliege-Raupe-Wanze. Also fragt man: sieht es eher aus wie ein Käfer, oder eher wie ein Wurm (z.B. auch Larve). Wenn ich mir das Bild so angucke, ...   *(kurz in Bezug auf Sprachentwicklungszeitskalen)

Comment: Nebenbei gibt es noch den "Drahtwurm", die Larve eines Käfers aus der Familie der Schnellkäfer (Elateridae) und den "Mehlwurm", ebenfalls eine Käferlarve (Familie der Schwarzkäfer / Tenebrionidae) sehen wirklich fast wie ein Wurm aus, haben aber sechs Beine :)

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen den *Tatzelwurm* (eines meiner Lieblingswörter, übrigens), dessen Haupteigenschaft ist, dass er eben Beine hat, und zwar durchaus einige davon, die er auch explizit im Namen trägt.